# Show Posts from Another WordPress Site

Tags: php, wordpress, feed, posts

I have 3 WordPress sites. I want to be able to add posts to one of the sites, and show some of the posts on the other two based on their categories.

E.g. site one has all posts, 
site two shows posts from site one with category 'site2'

Comment: Are your sites on the same domain? It might be an issue if they are on different domains.

Comment: They're not on the same domain no, but I control access to each of them. Wonder if I could put the db connection details in for each?

Comment: I'm sure there will be a cross domain issue with this!I used Jquery to show posts from one blog to a plain php site but it was on the same domain.. You can try use an RSS feed plugin to load the posts but it will link back to the main blog site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest thing to do is use RSS. See [FeedWordPress | simple and flexible Atom/RSS syndication for WordPress](http://feedwordpress.radgeek.com/) and [Developer's Guide - Google AJAX Feed API - Google Code](https://developers.google.com/feed/) and [Magpie RSS - PHP RSS Parser](http://magpierss.sourceforge.net/) for different ways to implement RSS feeds as links or import posts themselves.

Comment: FeedWordPress seems to work, but I'm having trouble with it showing Featured Images. Have you used it before?

Comment: Yes. That's a quesiton that's very specific to the plugin; ask in the plugin forums at wordpress.org